# Unable to move or resize object in Illustrator and Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am unable to move or resize objects in Illustrator and Photoshop. Sometimes it work, sometimes it doesn't. See this GIF:

[image: a demonstration]

I have tried uninstalling/installing Illustrator & Photoshop again, updating/downgrading, but still get the same issue.

I have also tried to delete settings using <kbd>CTRL + ALT + SHIFT</kbd> and restarting the program, but it doesn't do anything. It's supposed to bring a prompt asking to confirm, but there is no prompt. Illustrator just simply starts.

I am using the latest version of Adobe CC: 2015.2.1 64 bit.

After updating, Illustrator started, giving me an error that told me to update my graphics drivers.

Comment: @Jenna It doesn't have any option named release clipping mask.

Comment: Just this file or all files? -- this is tech support and off topic, by the way.

Comment: My bad, meant compound path. If this is happening on all files though, it is really odd.

Comment: Could you upload a file somewhere in which it isn't working? Also, what version of CS?

Comment: @jenna that option is also not available.

Comment: @tomCarpenter yes i can. But the issue is not with particular file. This issue with same with other files as well. I am using Latest Adobe CC 2015.2.1

Comment: If there is a hidden popup, you can `Shift + Right-Click` on the taskbar icon and **Cascade all windows**

Answer (score -2):

Try updating your pen tablet driver. That almost always fixes issues like this.

If you’re not using a pen tablet, go and get a pen tablet immediately. Illustrator is not designed to be used with a mouse, and your mouse and its software drivers are not designed to be used with Illustrator.

You can get a small Wacom Pen Tablet for about $60, and it will pay for itself in reduced work time within a week. And it will dramatically improve the quality of your work also.